# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'\x00\x00\x00\x00'

Tags: python, valueerror

I want to install wheel through pip but this error is occured.
How can I fix this?

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Installed Programs (D Drive)\Python372\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 143, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "D:\Installed Programs (D Drive)\Python372\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 318, in run
    resolver.resolve(requirement_set)
  File "D:\Installed Programs (D Drive)\Python372\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolve.py", line 102, in resolve
    self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req)
  File "D:\Installed Programs (D Drive)\Python372\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolve.py", line 256, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "D:\Installed Programs (D Drive)\Python372\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolve.py", line 209, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    self.require_hashes
  File "D:\Installed Programs (D Drive)\Python372\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 218, in prepare_linked_requirement
    req.populate_link(finder, upgrade_allowed, require_hashes)
  File "D:\Installed Programs (D Drive)\Python372\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_install.py", line 164, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "D:\Installed Programs (D Drive)\Python372\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index.py", line 572, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "D:\Installed Programs (D Drive)\Python372\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index.py", line 530, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "D:\Installed Programs (D Drive)\Python372\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index.py", line 675, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
  File "D:\Installed Programs (D Drive)\Python372\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index.py", line 793, in _get_page
    return _get_html_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "D:\Installed Programs (D Drive)\Python372\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index.py", line 144, in _get_html_page
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=0",
  File "D:\Installed Programs (D Drive)\Python372\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 525, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Installed Programs (D Drive)\Python372\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\download.py", line 396, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Installed Programs (D Drive)\Python372\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 503, in request
    prep.url, proxies, stream, verify, cert
  File "D:\Installed Programs (D Drive)\Python372\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 676, in merge_environment_settings
    env_proxies = get_environ_proxies(url, no_proxy=no_proxy)
  File "D:\Installed Programs (D Drive)\Python372\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\utils.py", line 760, in get_environ_proxies
    if should_bypass_proxies(url, no_proxy=no_proxy):
  File "D:\Installed Programs (D Drive)\Python372\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\utils.py", line 744, in should_bypass_proxies
    bypass = proxy_bypass(parsed.hostname)
  File "D:\Installed Programs (D Drive)\Python372\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\utils.py", line 93, in proxy_bypass
    return proxy_bypass_registry(host)
  File "D:\Installed Programs (D Drive)\Python372\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\utils.py", line 59, in proxy_bypass_registry
    'ProxyEnable')[0])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

Comment: Your proxy settings in your windows registry are corrupted, Python tries to load `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyEnable` is a 4-byte null, not a `'1'` or `'0'` string or a 32-bit DWORD integer number, as expected.

Comment: Thx for your Comment :)

Comment: I suspect that you have a `REG_BINARY` value instead of a `REG_DWORD` entry.

Answer (score 1):

you should modify type of ProxyEnable to REG_DWORD in registry HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyEnable

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).