# pip installation ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'\x00\x00\x00\x00'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I tried to install pipenv using pip, it keeps showing this same error message.

```
$ pip3 install pipenv
Collecting pipenv
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 188, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 345, in run
    resolver.resolve(requirement_set)
  File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\legacy_resolve.py", line 196, in resolve
    self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req)
  File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\legacy_resolve.py", line 359, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\legacy_resolve.py", line 305, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    abstract_dist = self.preparer.prepare_linked_requirement(
  File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 134, in prepare_linked_requirement
    req.populate_link(finder, upgrade_allowed, require_hashes)
  File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_install.py", line 211, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index.py", line 1200, in find_requirement
    candidates = self.find_candidates(
  File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index.py", line 1183, in find_candidates
    candidates = self.find_all_candidates(project_name)
  File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index.py", line 1128, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index.py", line 1282, in _get_pages
    page = _get_html_page(location, session=self.session)
  File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index.py", line 234, in _get_html_page
    resp = _get_html_response(url, session=session)
  File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index.py", line 165, in _get_html_response
    resp = session.get(
  File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 546, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\download.py", line 624, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 523, in request
    settings = self.merge_environment_settings(
  File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 700, in merge_environment_settings
    env_proxies = get_environ_proxies(url, no_proxy=no_proxy)
  File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\utils.py", line 761, in get_environ_proxies
    if should_bypass_proxies(url, no_proxy=no_proxy):
  File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\utils.py", line 745, in should_bypass_proxies
    bypass = proxy_bypass(parsed.hostname)
  File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\utils.py", line 95, in proxy_bypass
    return proxy_bypass_registry(host)
  File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\utils.py", line 60, in proxy_bypass_registry
    proxyEnable = int(winreg.QueryValueEx(internetSettings,
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

I'm using pip version 19.2.3, python version: 3.8.2, and my OS is Windows 10.

I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54577876/valueerror-invalid-literal-for-int-with-base-10-b-x00-x00-x00-x00) and I tried to find `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyEnable` path on registry but I can't find ProxyEnable directory.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgoRR.png)